Texture space Raytracing of cylinder primitive in godot shader for Helix interception
I have been trying to do raytracing of an helix in a spatial shader in godot 4.2, but apparently I missed something because the result is bloby and melty at the cylinder level.
The basics is that I trace a 2d circle in the depth plane along U, then try to extrude it as a cylinder by scaling the view vector by the t values given in 2d. But that didn't turn out as expected and I'm a loss of where it got wrong, the normal also don't look correct.
I have already try many permutation, originally I was doing two cylinder packed in sizzling, and removed one for reproduction and removing noise. I used the scratchpixel raytracing's article  notation.

uniform sampler2D text;

void fragment()
{
    mat3 TBN = mat3(TANGENT, BINORMAL, NORMAL);
    vec3 viewDirTangentSpace = TBN * VIEW;

    const float mydepth = 1.0;
    vec3 raydir = viewDirTangentSpace;///.5; // ray direction/depth

    const vec2 centers = vec2(-0.0,.5);//x and depth
    const float radius = 0.3;
    const float r2 = radius * radius;
    
    const vec2 UVsurfacePos = vec2(UV.x,0);

    //vector: 2d origine to circles center in 2d along vertical depth plane
    const vec2 L = centers.xy-UVsurfacePos.xy; const vec2 L2 = L*L;

    //dot projection: 2d centers to 2d ray line
    vec2 raydir2d = normalize(raydir.xz);
    float tca = dot(L,raydir2d);

    //2d distances to projected
    float distances = abs( (L2.x + L2.y) - (tca) );
    float d = sqrt( distances );float d2 = d * d;
    //float d2 = distances * distances;

    //2d intersections points
    float thcdiff = r2 - d2; float thc = sqrt (thcdiff);
    vec2 t = vec2(tca +thc, tca -thc);

    //get extrusion in y
    //vec3 p11 = vec3(UV,0) + raydir * t.x; //first impact column 1
    //vec3 p12 = vec3(UV,0) + raydir * t.y; //second impact column 1
    vec3 p11 = raydir * t.x; //first impact column 1
    vec3 p12 = raydir * t.y; //second impact column 1

    //get normal
    vec3 N11 = normalize( vec3(  (UV+p11.xz - centers),0) );
    vec3 N12 = normalize( vec3( -(UV+p12.xz - centers),0) );

    //get twist
    float twist11 = atan(N11.x, N11.y);
    float twist12 = atan(-N12.x, -N12.y);//reverse the N
    
    vec3 result = vec3(0.0); // black color if not intersecting
    
    if( t.x > 0.0 && t.y > 0.0 )
    {
        result = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // red color if intersecting cylinder1
    }

    float ptmin = min(t.x,t.y);
    vec2 UVoffset = UV+raydir.xy * ptmin;

    
    NORMAL = N11.xzy;
    ALBEDO = texture(text, UVoffset).xyz;
    

}

The helix interception is supposed to work in this way:

we find the hit point angle relative to the cylinder axis (using the normal orientation)
we find at which height of the cylinder, the similar angle of the spiral land (angle change linearly across height)
we compute if the hit point land with width of the spiral point at the same angle. else we discard.

